# How to use DateTime.Now.Hour?

Tags: c#, datetime

What I am trying to do:

I am trying to disaply tv listings from a an xml file by the current hour. Eg.. time now is 2pm, I want to disaply all listings from all channels at this current hour.

The below get the current date and matches it to the XMl files and displays all matches. I want to do the same for current hour.

If I change the method to below, I get this error:

Error   1   Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.DateTime' and 'int'

```
  bool MyDateCheckingMethod(string dateString)
            {
                DateTime otherDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyyMMddHHmmss K", null);
                // Is this today (ignoring time)?
                return otherDate.Date == DateTime.Now.Hour;
            }
```

This is what I am currently using to display by todays date and it works fine.

```
bool MyDateCheckingMethod(string dateString)
        {
            DateTime otherDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyyMMddHHmmss K", null);
            // Is this today (ignoring time)?
            return otherDate.Date == DateTime.Now.Date;
        }
```

Here is more of the code to make it a little clearer.

```
void c_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
                return;


            var r = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);





            listBox2.ItemsSource = from tv in r.Root.Descendants("programme")
                                   where tv.Attribute("channel").Value == "1200"
                                   where MyDateCheckingMethod(tv.Attribute("start").Value)
                                   let channelE1 = tv.Attribute("channel")
                                   let startE1 = tv.Attribute("start")
                                   let nameEl = tv.Element("title")
                                   orderby tv.Attribute("start").Value ascending
                                   let urlEl = tv.Element("desc")


                                   select new TV1guide



                                   {
                                       DisplayName = nameEl == null ? null : nameEl.Value,
                                       ChannelName = channelE1 == null ? null : channelE1.Value,
                                       ChannelURL = urlEl == null ? null : urlEl.Value,
                                       StartTime = startE1 == null ? (DateTime?)null : DateTime.ParseExact(startE1.Value, "yyyyMMddHHmmss zzz", DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal),



                                   };
```

Comment: Are you saying `return otherDate.Date.Hour == DateTime.Now.Date.Hour;` does not compile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you were getting is because you were trying to compare a date *and* time to an hour, rather than just comparing hours.  You can't compare an `int` to a `DateTime` directly.

Here's some code that would work:

```
bool MyDateCheckingMethod(string dateString)
{
    DateTime otherDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyyMMddHHmmss K", null);
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    // Is this the current date and hour?
    return otherDate.Date == now.Date
        && otherDate.Hour == now.Hour;
}
```

If you want to do the check just on the hour, and don't care if you match different dates, you can change the code to this:

```
bool MyDateCheckingMethod(string dateString)
{
    DateTime otherDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyyMMddHHmmss K", null);
    // Is this the current hour - regardless of date?
    return otherDate.Hour == DateTime.Now.Hour;
}
```

For similar problems in the future, I recommend that you [look up the docs on the `DateTime` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) to figure out exactly what each property returns.

Date and time handling is often more complicated than you'd initially think, and requires a bit of fore-knowledge on how the .Net framework handles time.  It often is helpful to look to the documentation, and to do a bit of experimentation in a separate scratch project.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I spent the last few hours reading over DateTime in MSDN but couldnt' figure it out. Its difficult to find real world tutorials to understand DateTime Class, or maybe i'm just slow :(

Comment: Is there any way to edit this to include +- 2 hours? So, listings that hours match +- 2 hours?

Comment: @Rhys: When in doubt, make a separate console project, and throw in just a tiny bit of the code you're confused about.  Get it compiling, and throw in a lot of `Console.WriteLine` lines.  E.g.: `Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);`, `Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.GetType());`, `Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Hour);`, and `Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Hour.GetType());`

Comment: @Rhys: Yes, but that's more complicated because hours wrap around...  I wouldn't be surprised if it isn't already answered elsewhere, too.  You might want to hit that search box at the top of the page.  If you don't find anything after a while, feel free to post another question :)

Comment: @Rhys: The answer will be something like `(otherDate - now).Duration <= TimeSpan.FromHours(2)`.  But please search for the question, and if you can't find it, post another question.  This would be useful information for other people, too.

Comment: I appreciate your help on this and the Console.Writeline is a great suggestions, Thanks. I searched for a realted question on here, but couldn't find one, so I have posted another question as it is beyond my understanding at my level.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
return otherDate.Hour == DateTime.Now.Hour;
```

However, this doesn't necessarily mean the same day, so maybe you are looking for:

```
return otherDate.Date == DateTime.Now.Date &&
       otherDate.Hour == DateTime.Now.Hour;
```

Comment: Perfect, Just what I was after, I didn't realise I have to match otherdate.hour and datetime.now.hour. Thanks for the quick response brian.